# Loop all SourceSets - Groovy -> Kotlin DSL

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

How to loop all source-sets in the kotlin DSL? The below groovy code loops all sourceSets including 'multiplicative' like androidTestFoobarProdDebug

```
flavorDimensions("brand", "releaseType")
productFlavors {
    create("prod") {
        dimension = "releaseType"
    }
    create("foobar") {
        dimension = "brand"
    }
}
sourceSets.all { com.android.build.api.dsl.AndroidSourceSet sourceSet ->
     // Also prints foorbarProd
     println("0 "+sourceSet.name)
}
sourceSets.all {
    println("1 "+it.name)
}
```

but this kotlin-code does not loop the multiplicative concatenated flavor-dimensions like foobarProdDebug

```
sourceSets.all { sourceSet ->
    println(sourceSet.name) // does not print foobarProd
    true // seems its a predicate in kotlin
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[People at Google](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/174001231) were so kind to help me out here:

Sadly this seems like the mixing of kotlin's all extension method on collection (which is not lazy) and gradle's DomainObjectContainer.all (which is lazy).

If you change

```
sourceSets.all { sourceSet -> //: com.android.build.api.dsl.AndroidSourceSet ->
    println("sourceSet.name = \"src/${name}/svg\"")
    true // seems its a predicate in kotlin
}
```

to

```
sourceSets.all {// this: com.android.build.api.dsl.AndroidSourceSet ->
    println("sourceSet.name = \"src/${name}/svg\"")
    // Not a kotlin.sequences.all call anymore so nothing to return
}
```

it works.

Here's the full kotlin solution:

```
flavorDimensions("brand", "releaseType")
productFlavors {
    create("prod") {
        dimension = "releaseType"
    }
    create("foobar") {
        dimension = "brand"
    }
}
sourceSets.all {
    println(name)
}
```